# Google App Engine Update Issue

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I am working on an application (python based), which is deployed on GAE, it was working fine till last day, but I can't seem to update any code on app engine since this morning, it is complaining about some sort of issue with password, I have double checked and email id and password are correct.

here is the stack trace which I receive:

```
10:47 PM Cloning 706 static files.
2012-11-03 22:47:07,913 WARNING appengine_rpc.py:542 ssl module not found.
Without the ssl module, the identity of the remote host cannot be verified, and
connections may NOT be secure. To fix this, please install the ssl module from
http://pypi.python.org/pypi/ssl .
To learn more, see https://developers.google.com/appengine/kb/general#rpcssl 
Password for user@gmail.com: 2012-11-03 22:47:07,913 ERROR appcfg.py:2266 An unexpected error occurred. Aborting. 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 2208, in DoUpload
    missing_files = self.Begin()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 1934, in Begin
    CloneFiles('/api/appversion/cloneblobs', blobs_to_clone, 'static')
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 1929, in CloneFiles
    result = self.Send(url, payload=BuildClonePostBody(chunk))
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 1841, in Send
    return self.rpcserver.Send(url, payload=payload, **self.params)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appengine_rpc.py", line 403, in Send
    self._Authenticate()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appengine_rpc.py", line 543, in _Authenticate
    super(HttpRpcServer, self)._Authenticate()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appengine_rpc.py", line 293, in _Authenticate
    credentials = self.auth_function()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 2758, in GetUserCredentials
    password = self.raw_input_fn(password_prompt)
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
10:47 PM Rolling back the update.
2012-11-03 22:47:08,818 WARNING appengine_rpc.py:542 ssl module not found.
Without the ssl module, the identity of the remote host cannot be verified, and
connections may NOT be secure. To fix this, please install the ssl module from
http://pypi.python.org/pypi/ssl .
To learn more, see https://developers.google.com/appengine/kb/general#rpcssl 
Password for user@gmail.com: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\appcfg.py", line 171, in 
    run_file(__file__, globals())
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\appcfg.py", line 167, in run_file
    execfile(script_path, globals_)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 4322, in 
    main(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 4313, in main
    result = AppCfgApp(argv).Run()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 2599, in Run
    self.action(self)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 4048, in __call__
    return method()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 3065, in Update
    self.UpdateVersion(rpcserver, self.basepath, appyaml)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 3047, in UpdateVersion
    lambda path: self.opener(os.path.join(basepath, path), 'rb'))
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 2267, in DoUpload
    self.Rollback()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 2150, in Rollback
    self.Send('/api/appversion/rollback')
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 1841, in Send
    return self.rpcserver.Send(url, payload=payload, **self.params)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appengine_rpc.py", line 403, in Send
    self._Authenticate()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appengine_rpc.py", line 543, in _Authenticate
    super(HttpRpcServer, self)._Authenticate()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appengine_rpc.py", line 293, in _Authenticate
    credentials = self.auth_function()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 2758, in GetUserCredentials
    password = self.raw_input_fn(password_prompt)
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
2012-11-03 22:47:09 (Process exited with code 1)

You can close this window now.
```

Any Help will be appreciated.

P.S, I have tried from command line as well as Google app engine launcher.

Comment: Which SDK version you using & python version?

Comment: Can you download your original source that is currently running and deploy that to make sure it's not something with your local SDK? The end-of-file you are getting is an exception raised when you try to read a file, but don't get any data.

Comment: @Niks I am using Python 2.5 and sdk version 1.7.3.

Comment: @Sologoub, I am not sure about that, how can I download the code from server?

Comment: Ohk..Did you deployed your last code on same sdk version(mean 1.7.3)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After 3 days of endless searching, I have figured out the problem, if you are facing this issue, first thing you have to check is your system time, mine was incorrect due to daylight saving changes.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

To download you existing deployed code, Please have look at [download appengine files](http://www.labnol.org/software/download-appengine-files/19348/)
and [download deployed code](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadinganapp#Downloading_Source_Code) links.

This could help you out to download your code.

And try it to re-upload again, and see its working or not.